# Matrix Exponentiation Algorithm for large values of N

Tags: algorithm, matrix, fibonacci

I want to calculate the Fibonacci of very large value of N ie. 10^6 with a complexity of O(logN).
Here is my code but it gives the result for 10^6 in 30 seconds which is very time consuming.Help me point out the mistake.I have to give the output in modulo 10^9+7.

```
static BigInteger mod=new BigInteger("1000000007");

BigInteger fibo(long n){
    BigInteger F[][] = {{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE},{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ZERO}};
    if(n == 0)
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    power(F, n-1);
    return F[0][0].mod(mod);
}

void power(BigInteger F[][], long n) {
    if( n == 0 || n == 1)
        return;
    BigInteger M[][] = {{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ONE},{BigInteger.ONE,BigInteger.ZERO}};
    power(F, n/2);
    multiply(F, F);
    if( n%2 != 0 )
        multiply(F, M);
  }

void multiply(BigInteger F[][], BigInteger M[][]){
    BigInteger x =  (F[0][0].multiply(M[0][0])).add(F[0][1].multiply(M[1][0])) ;
    BigInteger y =  F[0][0].multiply(M[0][1]).add(F[0][1].multiply(M[1][1])) ;
    BigInteger z =  F[1][0].multiply(M[0][0]).add( F[1][1].multiply(M[1][0]));
    BigInteger w =  F[1][0].multiply(M[0][1]).add(F[1][1].multiply(M[1][1]));

    F[0][0] = x;
    F[0][1] = y;
    F[1][0] = z;
    F[1][1] = w;
}
```

Comment: Can't you do everything with 64-bit integers instead of BigIntegers? You're doing modulo ~1e9 anyway.

Comment: It worth noting that the n-th Fibonacci number has a closed form expression that can be computed _exactly_ for any n, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

Answer (score 7):

Use these [recurrences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Matrix_form):

> *F*<sub>2*n*−1</sub> = *F*<sub>*n*</sub><sup>2</sup> + *F*<sub>*n*−1</sub><sup>2</sup>
>
> *F*<sub>2*n*</sub> = (2*F*<sub>*n*−1</sub> + *F*<sub>*n*</sub>) *F*<sub>*n*</sub>

together with [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). For example, in Python you could use the [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator, like this:

```py
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fibonacci_modulo(n, m):
    """Compute the nth Fibonacci number modulo m."""
    if n <= 3:
        return (0, 1, 1, 2)[n] % m
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        a = fibonacci_modulo(n // 2 - 1, m)
        b = fibonacci_modulo(n // 2, m)
        return ((2 * a + b) * b) % m
    else:
        a = fibonacci_modulo(n // 2, m)
        b = fibonacci_modulo(n // 2 + 1, m)
        return (a * a + b * b) % m
```

this computes the 10<sup>6</sup>th Fibonacci number (modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7) in a few microseconds:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:fibonacci_modulo(10 ** 6, 10 ** 9 + 7), number=1)
0.000083282997366
```

Answer (score 4):

I get a more reasonable - although still very slow - time of `real    0m2.335s` using your code.

The algorithm to compute the Fibonacci numbers is okay (there are some tweaks that could speed it up somewhat, but nothing very dramatic), so the problem is that operations on large `BigInteger`s are slow, and `F(10^6)` has nearly 700,000 bits.

Since you want to compute the remainder modulo `mod = 10^9 + 7`, and `(mod-1)^2` fits in a `long`, you can get a much faster implementation using `long`s instead of `BigInteger`s, computing the remainder in each step. The direct transcription

```
public class FiboL {

    static final long mod = 1000000007L;

     static long fibo(long n){

          long F[][] = {{1,1},{1,0}};

          if(n == 0)
            return 0;
          power(F, n-1);
            return F[0][0]; //.mod(mod);
        }

    static void power(long F[][], long n){

          if( n == 0 || n == 1)
              return;
          long M[][] = {{1,1},{1,0}};

          power(F, n/2);
          multiply(F, F);

          if( n%2 != 0 )
             multiply(F, M);
        }

    static void multiply(long F[][], long M[][]){

          long x =  (F[0][0] * M[0][0]) % mod + (F[0][1] * M[1][0]) % mod;
          long y =  (F[0][0] * M[0][1]) % mod + (F[0][1] * M[1][1]) % mod;
          long z =  (F[1][0] * M[0][0]) % mod + (F[1][1] * M[1][0]) % mod;
          long w =  (F[1][0] * M[0][1]) % mod + (F[1][1] * M[1][1]) % mod;

          F[0][0] = x % mod;
          F[0][1] = y % mod;
          F[1][0] = z % mod;
          F[1][1] = w % mod;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(fibo(1000000));
    }
}
```

runs in `real    0m0.083s`.