# OverFlowError while solving "Number of subsets without consecutive numbers"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to solve a problem in TalentBuddy using Python

The problem is :

> Given a number N. Print to the standard output the total number of
>   subsets that can be formed using the {1,2..N} set, but making sure
>   that none of the subsets contain any two consecutive integers. The
>   final count might be very large, this is why you must print the result
>   modulo 524287.

I've worked the code. All of the tests are OK, except Test 6. I got `OverFlowError` when the test is submitting `10000000` as the argument of my function. I don't know what should I do to resolve this error

My code :

```
import math
def count_subsets(n):
    step1 = (1 / math.sqrt(5)) * (((1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (n + 2))
    step2 = (1 / math.sqrt(5)) * (((1 - math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (n + 2))
    res = step1 - step2
    print int(res) % 524287
```

I guess this is taking up memory a lot. I wrote this after I found a mathematical formula to the same topic on the Internet.
[image: mathematical formula]
I guess my code isn't Pythonic at all.

How to do this, the "Pythonic" way? How to resolve the `OverFlowError`?

**EDIT**: In the problem, I've given the example input `3`, and the result (output) is `5`.

Explanation: The 5 sets are, `{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1,3}`.

However, in Test 6, the problem I've given are:

Summary for test #6

### Input test:

`[10000000]`

### Expected output:

`165366`

### Your output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  On line 4, in function count_subsets:
    step1 = (1 / math.sqrt(5)) * (((1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (n + 2))
OverflowError:
```

Comment: Split you step1 and step2 to mini steps, i tried it and i had no errors, the result was 0 so maybe there is some other problem. also try to use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal)

Comment: How precise do you need the solution. What output do you expect from count_subsets() ?

Comment: @IntrepidBrit I edited out the question, written the example input/output, and the error test

Comment: Next question: Why do you take the integer & modulus? Python is more than capable of handling those large numbers. My local test code is happily chomping though those numbers with ridiculous precision.

Comment: @IntrepidBrit First of all, the exact words from the problem : "The final count might be very large, this is why you must print the result modulo 524287"

Second, `res` will contain floating number (ex. `5.0`), and the example output is an integer. So in the end I converted `res` into an integer

Comment: Well, although the value is very large, you don't need to take the modulo when using Decimals. In fact, by casting to int can be a lengthy process if you have sufficient precision. Give me a few minutes - I'll throw an answer together.

Comment: @RyoArmanda - Could you link us to where you found the mathematical simplification?

Comment: @IntrepidBrit I found the mathematical expression through [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~lyuu/dm/2013/20130516.pdf‎/). I cannot confirm this is true or not. Maybe is there another statemnet?

Comment: @RyoArmanda - what version of Python does TalentBuddy use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let f(N) be the number of subsets that contain no consecutive numbers. There's F(N-2) subsets that contain N, and F(N-1) subsets that don't contain N. This gives:

```
F(N) = F(N-1) + F(N-2).

F(0) = 1 (there's 1 subset of {}, namely {}).
F(1) = 2 (there's 2 subsets of {1}, namely {} and {1}).
```

This is the fibonacci sequence, albeit with non-standard starting conditions.

There is, as you've found, a formula using the golden ratio to calculate this. The problem is that for large N, you need more and more accuracy in your floating-point calculation.

An exact way to do the calculation is to use iteration:

```
a_0 = 1
b_0 = 2
a_{n+1} = b_n
b_{n+1} = a_n + b_n
```

The naive version of this is easy but slow.

```
def subsets(n, modulo):
    a, b = 1, 2
    for _ in xrange(n):
        a, b = b, (a + b) % modulo
    return a
```

Instead, a standard trick is to write the repeated application of the recurrences as a matrix power:

```
( a_n ) = | 0 1 |^N  ( 1 )
( b_n ) = | 1 1 |  . ( 2 )
```

You can compute the matrix power (using modulo-524287 arithmetic) by repeated squaring. See [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). Here's complete code:

```
def mul2x2(a, b, modulo):
    result = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
    for i in xrange(2):
        for j in xrange(2):
            for k in xrange(2):
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]
                result[i][j] %= modulo
    return result

def pow(m, n, modulo):
    result = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
    while n:
        if n % 2: result = mul2x2(result, m, modulo)
        m = mul2x2(m, m, modulo)
        n //= 2
    return result

def subsets(n):
    m = pow([[0, 1], [1, 1]], n, 524287)
    return (m[0][0] + 2 * m[0][1]) % 524287

for i in xrange(1, 10):
    print i, subsets(i)
for i in xrange(1, 20):
    print i, subsets(10 ** i)
```

This prints solutions for every power of 10 up to 10^19, and it's effectively instant (0.041sec real on my laptop).

Comment: This code is so good! I didn't even know you can approach this by matrices, and somehow you managed it to run really fast. Big props to you!

Comment: related: [nth fibonacci number in sublinear time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1525521/4279), especially [this answer that also based on the matrix power](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1526036/4279).

Comment: [Here's another implementation of a fast Fibonacci recurrence.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14782458/68063)