# How to make fibonacci method?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I want to get the value of the fibonacci, not the previous number. For example:

```
public class Fibonacci {

    public static int f(int n){
        if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
        } else {
            return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
        }
    }
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println(f(4));
    }
}
```

the method outputs 3. I want to obtain 4+3 = 7.
How can I do it?

Comment: Search in Google by Fibonacci and not Fibocanni. This algorithm is widely used as an example of recursion. (thx @BobJarvis for editing the question).

Comment: 7 is not a Fibonacci number.

Comment: 7 is not a Fibonacci number *at all*, let alone the *fourth* Fibonacci number.

Comment: What should the method do? Return the `i`-th Fibonacci number?

Comment: @lurker: coffee. Need...coffee........

Answer (score 2):

The [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) reads:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 ...
```

The *base-case* is simply wrong:

```
@Cacheable
public static int f(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {//base case
        return 1;  //first two numbers are 1
    } else {
        return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2);
    }
}
```

This gives for `4`: `3`.

> **Note**: these are not *"array indices"*, but *"human indices"*.

But this method is actually way too inefficient to be pratical. You should use *dynamic programming* or an iterative variant to calculate this.

`@Cacheable` is a [spring-directive](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) that turns a function into a function with memory. In other words, once `f(4)` is calculated, it will not recalculate it, but get it from a store. Removing `@Cacheable` will still give the correct result, but will take way too much time for a large *n*.

This thus turns the algorithm in an efficient *dynamic programming* approach.

An iterative algorithm is thus:

```
public static int f(int n){
    if (n <= 2) {//base case
        return 1;  //first two numbers are 1
    } else {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            int t = a+b;
            a = b;
            b = t;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Since this runs in linear time whereas the previous one takes exponential time.

[**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/hL).

Or as @Jarlax says, you can also compute this in *O(log n)* time using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781543/matrix-exponentiation-algorithm-for-large-values-of-n).

Comment: There is also nice algo involving matrix [[0, 1], [1, 1]] power -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781543/matrix-exponentiation-algorithm-for-large-values-of-n.

Comment: @Jarlax: thanks. Its included in the answer, although describing the algorithm is harder because of the more complex mathematics involved.